# How to use variables with inputboxes and msgboxes?

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently trying to make a vb script that goes kind of like this

```
Dim Name
Name = Inputbox ("Please enter your name","Name","")
MsgBox ("Haha, your name " & Name "sucks!")
```

And have it so it uses the persons name that was saved in an input box. My only problem is I can't add text after the variable is used. I however cannot get the right syntax and keep getting errors. If anyone knows how to right this code please help!

Comment: how are you trying to add more text to the variable?

Comment: You are missing an `&`. All strings, whether a literal (text in the code) or variable (containing text) are concatenated with `&`. `MsgBox "Haha, your name " & Name & "sucks!"`. PS No brackets when calling a sub, only use brackets when calling functions that return values.

Comment: @Noodles not entirely true you can use brackets with a `Sub` if you prefix it with `Call MsgBox("Haha, your name " & Name & " sucks!")`. Prefer to do this as it distinguishes Subs clearly in code.